# Need help creating macro in excel rows to columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I have a data dump in Excel that consists of customer_id data with multiple equipment listed against the same customer.

Data looks like this;

```
customer_id    equipment 
1               xx
1               yy
1               zz
2               xx
2               yy
2               zz
2               xx
```

I want to data into a worksheet where there's one row per customer_id 
customer_id equipment_1 #_equipment_1 equipment_2 #_equipment_2

Comment: I tried to format your question so it's easier to understand, but it seems the last paragraph is incomplete. Can you [edit] it so it makes more sense? Please also include what version of Excel you are using and what you've already tried.

Comment: Please provide a same of what the output would be.

Comment: See if this helps: http://superuser.com/q/366616/76571

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is called a Cross-tab in database lingo or a Pivot Table in spreadsheets. Use the PivotTable in Excel. You will need to refer to Excel's help to create it, the instructions are beyond the scope of this post.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest creating a PivotTable with RecordMacro - results for me as below:

```
Sub Macro1()
        Columns("A:B").Select
        ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
            "Sheet1!R1C1:R1048576C2", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable _
            TableDestination:="Sheet1!R1C4", TableName:="PivotTable2", DefaultVersion _
            :=xlPivotTableVersion12
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        Cells(1, 4).Select
        ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = True
        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("equipment")
            .Orientation = xlColumnField
            .Position = 1
        End With
        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("customer_id")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
        End With
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
            "PivotTable2").PivotFields("equipment"), "Count of equipment", xlCount
    End Sub
```